# TcpListener not working for other machine ip: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I have created one TCP listener which works fine, if i set it to listen to an ip for current machine, where the listener application is running. But, when i set it to listen to an ip of some other machine, of same network, it throws exception

`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in its context`.

Is it like, TCP listener can listen only to ips assigned to the machine where its running? Could some one please explain this?

Comment: You are right: "TCP listener can listen only to ips assigned to the machine where its running". `TcpListener` is a class to handle incoming tcp clients/requests... since you (should) have no idea about other machine's traffic, it is indeed invalid to use other IPs here. You cannot handle requests targetting other machines ;-)

Comment: @olydis: That's an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are right: "TCP listener can listen only to ips assigned to the machine where its running".

`TcpListener` is a class to handle incoming tcp clients/requests... since you (should) have no idea about other machine's traffic, it is indeed invalid to use other IPs here.

You cannot handle requests targetting other machines ;-)